# Solve not satisfying simple boundary conditions

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following equations for the coefficients `c1` and `c2`.

```
w[x_] := c1*(1 - x)  
a[x_] := c2*(1 - x)
```

Given the constraints:

```
Solve[(1 + w[x]*a[x]) == (1/x) && w[0] == wmax && a[1] == 0 , {c1, c2}]
```

Mathematica gives me:

```
{{c1->wmax,c2->1/((x-x^2) wmax)}}
```

However when plugging the formula for `c2` into `a`, the condition `a[1] == 0` is not satisfied. Instead of being zero, `a[1] == 1/wmax`.

How can I convince `Solve` to generate a `c2` that truly makes `a[1] == 0`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  I have formatted the post for better readability.  Please click the `edit` link above to see how to do this for your next post.

Comment: As you can see from the syntax colouring the the notebook interface, `C` is a defined system symbol. It is used for several purposes by the system. Make sure you never use a system symbol where you need an undefined one! Even if it hasn't caused trouble in this example, it will sooner or later. (Actually there was a post a couple of days ago where using `C` did cause problems.) In general, it is good practice never to use symbols starting with capitals.  All system symbols start with a capital, so if your own ones start with a lowercase, you can be sure you won't run into this kind of trouble.

Comment: Thanks very much Szabolcs, I've replaced C with x in the post (the problem persists though).

Comment: Given the definitions of `w[x]` and `a[x]` the equation `a[1] == 0` is identically true, therefore no condition for `c2` is needed.

Comment: Someone will surely post a more mathematically sound answer, but the problem is the following: notice that `a[1] == 0` holds for any *constant* `c2` (i.e. independent of `x`). The remaining two conditions tell you that `c1` and `c2` must depend on `x` the way you posted in your answer.  This `c2 == 1/(wmax x - wmax x^2)` is undefined for `x==1` (1/0), but taking the limit `x -> 1` gives `a[x] -> 1/wmax` (and not 0).  It's a good example of a simple problem where you can't just blindly input equations into a CAS and look at what comes out.  You need to be careful and look at what is happening.

Comment: Thank you Artes, and Szabolcs for clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) it works for me.

```
w[x_] := c1*(1 - x)
a[x_] := c2*(1 - x)

eqns = (1 + w[x]*a[x]) == (1/x) && w[0] == wmax && a[1] == 0;
sol = Solve[eqns, {c1, c2}]

(* {{c1 -> wmax, c2 -> -(1/(wmax (-x + x^2)))}} *)

Simplify[eqns /. sol]

(* {True} *)
```

(2) a[1] evaluates to 0 independently of solution values.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I am still a little confused, if I substitue `c2` into `a` I have:

`a[x_] := (1 - x)*-1/(wmax (-x + x^2))`

`a[1] = Indeterminate`

And the limit approaches `1/wmax` as `x->1`.